# Wrap text in a UILabel with quotes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

By default, UILabels truncate text and then put an ellipsis on the end.

How might I wrap all the text, including the ellipse, in double quotes?

Answer (score 2):

Use two `UILable`s, the first holds the text (plus an open-quote), and the second just holds a close-quote:

```
["text that is lon…]["]
```

Comment: Yes! Don't complicate things if you don't have to. Wrap this in a seperate class, like QuotedLabel, so you don't pollute your code with extra UILabels, and you're done.

Comment: It works well for one-line label. For multi-line one it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
UILabel *label;
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation;
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood it. The OP is currently getting '"Some line of ...' and they want '"Some... of text"', which setting middle truncation will give them.

Comment: I've been looking for middle truncation, at least you helped me with this answer :D

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's an even better convenience method on the iPhone that I don't know about, I think the easiest and most flexible thing to do would be to subclass UILabel and implement your own drawing and truncation, using the various sizeWithFont extensions to determine the width of the string and each set of quotes individually.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to set the font/color of the quotes using this method?

Answer (score 0):

Is your label text predictably going to result in truncation (and thus always have the ellipse)? I doubt it, but in case it does, you know the content is going to basically fill the width, so you can make the quote marks other UILabels (or even images). This would give you font and color control as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a correct way to do this, but it won't be the simplest thing ever.  You need to do the following:

Determine the max height and max width of your label, with quotes.  Determine the actual size of the label.  You can use sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: to do this.  If the first is smaller than the second, strip the last word from your text, add ellipsis, and try again.  That will look something like:

```
NSString *nextLine = rawTextWithoutQuotes;
NSRange range = [nextLine rangeOfString: @" " options: NSBackwardsSearch];
if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
    return nextLine;
} else {
    nextLine = [nextLine substringToIndex: range.location];
}
```

Keep doing this until you have manually truncated your string, then add the quotes and ellipsis, put it in your label, and you're done.