# How do I wrap truncated text in a SwiftUI Text with quotes?

Tags: text, swiftui, truncation

I want to achieve exactly the same effect as [specified by this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964903/wrap-text-in-a-uilabel-with-quotes), except in SwiftUI. That is, I want a `Text` object set to `.lineLimit(3).truncationMode(.tail)` that will render the text, including the trailing ellipsis, inside proper typographical quotation marks, like so: `“It was the best of times, it was...”`

The [best solution for the problem in UIKit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1965188/17294) won't transfer over to SwiftUI in the obvious way:

```
Text("“\(transcript)").lineLimit(3).truncationMode(.tail) + Text("”") // error
```

Xcode complains that "Cannot convert value of type 'some View' to expected argument type 'Text'", as the type of the return of `lineLimit(_:)` and `truncationMode(_:)` aren't `Text` and therefore concatenation with `+` isn't allowed. I couldn't get any combination of casts or wrapping various parts in `@ViewBuilder`s to work, which makes sense. They're different types.

Is there any way of doing this without  basically re-implementing `.lineLimit(_:)` myself?

Comment: You should concatenate it at model level, like `Text(text1 + text2 + text3).lineLimit(3).truncationMode(.tail)`

Comment: That will truncate away the trailing quote in `text3` won't it? As above, I want the trailing quote included.

Answer (score 0):

The best way we found so far is to kind of define the problem away, which maybe turns out to be a better typographic solution anyway:

```
HStack(spacing: 0) {
    VStack {
        Text("“")
        Spacer()
    }
    HStack {
        Text("Very long text to be truncated goes here")
            .lineLimit(2)
    }
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        Text("”")
    }
}
```

This puts the quote characters to the left and right of the text, which is kind of what you want for a "pull quote" anyway.

[image: The SwiftUI snippet above, rendered to demonstrate how the quote marks are to the left and right of the body of truncated text]

*Edit:* I just realised that unfortunately this has an issue—if the text is too short to be truncated, you end up with blank space before the quotes: `“Like this.             ”`